# Restoring textbox value is not working in my scenario

Tags: jquery

With my code I am clearing textbox data based on condition and trying to restore on focus. HTML code size is very large so I am not posting here, I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mq8SC/4/).

My code is explained with comments in that fiddle. Text restoring on focus is returning me null value.
But it works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B77nt/6/)

Comment: dont use live in 1.7 it coult be a problem

Comment: ` // Whenever a keyup event occured in textbox if the value length is greater than the nearest checkbox/radio button ` ???

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes.. There will be one radio button in the parent <tr> of the textbox.. You can find in HTML given in fiddle.

Comment: You really need to do cache the jquery object `$(this);` by making `var $this = $(this);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some flaws in your code:

- `</input>` should not be used. Instead, use self-closing tags `<input ... />`
- `parents()` should be `closest()`. It is possible that `parents()` select multiple elements
- Remove `.not(this)`, and add the following:

  ```
  if (this == _this)  {
      tt.data('text',tt.val());
  }
  else {
      tt.val('');
  }
  ```
- Replace the function at `blur()` by:

  ```
  if(ss.val(ss.data('text')).val().length > 0) ss.closest('tr').find('.humble').prop('checked', true)
  ```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mq8SC/9/

Answer (score 2):

The problem:
after each(!) keyup or change event in one text input field you store the values of all other text input fields, but after the first time the input fields are empty and the stored value will be overwritten with the current value (an empty string).
E.g.: overwrite only the stored value, if the string isn't empty?

Also see the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/Mq8SC/8/).